# Fraction and among

Tags: prepositions

Is the sentence bellow correct? I mean to say is the `among` preposition correct for the `fraction`(Z = X/Y)?

> Z is calculated as a fraction of X among Y.

Answer (score 1):

*Fraction* actually means a part of a whole, or a portion of a group.

> The number of car owners who actually get regular oil changes is only a **fraction** of what it should be.

In other contexts the fraction X/Y represents the *proportion* X to Y.  *Among* can make sense if you're talking about the proportion of populations of objects.

> The **proportion** of juvenile animals **among** the entire herd is surprisingly high.

This doesn't sound quite right, but it would be understood.  A better phrasing might be:

> The proportion of juvenile animals **to** the population of the entire herd is surprisingly high.

You can also express fractions as *ratios*,

> Z is the **ratio** of X over Y.

Or you can just say

> Z is equal to X **over** Y.

Comment: [*They define four parameters: Sensitivity, a measure of positivity in disease, is **the fraction of patients with the disease** giving positive test results.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+the+fraction+of+patients+with+the+disease%22) Doesn't seem unreasonable to me.